# Count only string values in a row

Tags: r

I have a data that looks as follows:

```
    Patent_number<-c(2323,4449,4939,4939,12245)
    IPC_class_1<-c("C12N",4,"C29N00185",2,"C12F")
    IPC_class_2<-c(3,"K12N","C12F","A01N",8)
    IPC_class_3<-c("S12F",1,"CQ010029393049",5,"CQ1N")
    
    df<-data.frame(Patent_number, IPC_class_1, IPC_class_2, IPC_class_3)
    View(df)
```

I want to count only the number o (string) values such as C12N, A01N etc. per row by adding another column "counts" in the end of the data frame. In other words, I want to exclude the numeric values from the row count.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have mixed types in a dataframe column, so all of the numeric values will also be stored as type `character`. One approach would be to convert everything using `as.numeric`, and then use `is.na` to count those that are not coercible to numeric...

```
df$counts <- apply(sapply(df, as.numeric), 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

df
  Patent_number IPC_class_1 IPC_class_2 IPC_class_3 counts
1          2323        C12N           3        S12F      2
2          4449           4        K12N           1      1
3          4939        C29N        C12F        CQ01      3
4          4939           2        A01N           5      1
5         12245        C12F           8        CQ1N      2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it worked and comprehensible. May I add follow-up question: I have edited my example above slighty. Is their a way to only count know the character values having 4-digits. So "C12N" should be counted, but "C29N00185" not for the row sum.

Comment: Building on the previous answer, this gives the number of 4-character strings in each line: `df$fours <- apply(sapply(df, as.character), 1, function(x) sum(nchar(x) == 4))`

Comment: That's interesting.  Could you check you used a lower case x, in both the `function(x)` and `nchar(x)`?

Answer (score 1):

We may also count by checking if all the characters are digits

```
df$counts <- ncol(df) - Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, grepl, pattern = '^[0-9.]+$'))
df$counts
[1] 2 1 3 1 2
```